# Getting NullInjectorError: No provider for Store error when trying to run Angular tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, redux, ngrx, angular-test

app.component.ts

```
...
constructor(private store: Store<fromAppState.AppState>) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromAppActions.Load());
...
```

app.state.ts

```
export interface AppState {
  structure: Structure;
  buttons: number[];
  bars: Bar[];
  limit: number;
  isLoading: boolean;
  error: string;
}
export const initialState: AppState = {
  buttons: [],
  structure: null,
  bars: [],
  limit: 0,
  isLoading: false,
  error: '',
};
const getState = createFeatureSelector<AppState>('myApp');
...
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
 describe('AppComponent', () => {
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-loader',
    template: '<div></div>',
  })
  class FakeLoaderComponent {
    @Input() loading: boolean;
  }
  let component: AppComponent;
  let mockStore: MockStore;
  let mockBarsSelector: MemoizedSelector<fromAppState.AppState, Bar[]>;
  // const storeMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('Store', ['select']);
  let buttons$: Observable<number[]> = of([45, 23, -8, -12]);
  let buttons: number[] = [45, 23, -8, -12];
  let loading$: Observable<boolean> = of(true);
  let structure: Structure = {
    buttons: [45, 23, -8, -12],
    bars: [15, 34, 7, 87],
    limit: 150,
  };
  let barsObject: Bar[] = [
    { value: 15, newValue: Math.round(15 * 100) / 150 },
    { value: 34, newValue: Math.round(34 * 100) / 150 },
    { value: 7, newValue: Math.round(7 * 100) / 150 },
    { value: 87, newValue: Math.round(87 * 100) / 150 },
  ];
  
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
   
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        MaterialModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({}, {}),
      ],
      declarations: [AppComponent, FakeLoaderComponent],
      providers: [provideMockStore()],
    }).compileComponents();
    component.bars = barsObject;
    component.limit = structure.limit;
    component.selectedProgressBar = -1;
    component.componentActive = true;
    component.buttons$ = buttons$;
    component.loading$ = loading$;

    mockStore = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
    mockStore.overrideSelector(fromAppState.getIsLoading, false);
    mockStore.overrideSelector(fromAppState.getBars, barsObject);
    mockStore.overrideSelector(fromAppState.getButtons, buttons);
    mockStore.overrideSelector(fromAppState.getStructure, structure);
    mockStore.overrideSelector(fromAppState.getError, '');
    mockBarsSelector = mockStore.overrideSelector(
      fromAppState.getBars,
      barsObject
    );
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, LoaderComponent],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}, {}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]),
    StoreModule.forFeature('myApp', AppReducer),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      name: 'My DevTools',
      maxAge: 50,
      logOnly: environment.production,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AppService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When I run `ng test` I get this error:
Failed: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Store -> Store]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'Store', 'Store' ] })
at Jasmine

Do I need to import the reducer to the spec file as well?

Comment: I don't think you have to use `StoreModule.forRoot()` when you already have `provideMockStore()`. If it still doesn't work, could you create a StackBlitz ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the component after the TestBed is configured.

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        MaterialModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({}, {}),
      ],
      declarations: [AppComponent, FakeLoaderComponent],
      providers: [provideMockStore()],
    }).compileComponents();


// do this AFTER configuration

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

And as Andrei mentioned in the comments, you can only use the real Store or `provideMockStore` - it's not possible to use both at the same time AFAIK, this might lead to strange behaviors.